# Multiple configurable swatches on product listing page Magento 1.9

Tags: php, attributes, magento-1.9, configurable-product

I want to show multiple configurable swatches on product listing page. For that I created configurable_category.phtml where I replicated configurable.phtml file to showing the configurable swatches:

```
$_product    = $this->getProduct();
$_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());
$_jsonConfig = $this->getJsonConfig();
$_renderers  = $this->getChild('attr_renderers')->getSortedChildren();

....

$_rendered = false;
foreach ($_renderers as $_rendererName):
    $_renderer = $this->getChild('attr_renderers')->getChild($_rendererName);
    if (method_exists($_renderer, 'shouldRender') && $_renderer->shouldRender($_attribute, $_jsonConfig)):
        $_renderer->setProduct($_product);
        $_renderer->setAttributeObj($_attribute);
        echo $_renderer->toHtml();
        $_rendered = true;
        break;
    endif;
endforeach;

....
```

Now I have to include this code:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.options.configurable.renderers" as="attr_renderers" />
```

But I don't know where to include it. I've tried to put it in **catalog.xml** under the **catalog_category_default** and **catalog_category_layered** but `$_renderers = $this->getChild('attr_renderers');` still returns false.

Can anyone help me with that?